# Ruby: Grouping a date range by year and month

Tags: ruby, date

I am creating a range for each month in my example range.

```
example_range = (Time.zone.today..2.years.from_now)
```

Output should look like so:

```
=> [Wed, 03 Aug 2016..Wed, 31 Aug 2016, Thu, 01 Sep 2016..Fri,
30 Sep 2016, Sat, 01 Oct 2016..Mon, 03 Oct 2016, ...]
```

At the moment I'm doing this, which doesn't work for ranges longer than a year, because the grouping will put January '16 and January '17 in one group.

```
example_range.group_by(&:month).each { |_, month| month.first..month.last }
```

I also tried this, but ruby segfaults on this for some reason...

```
example_range.group_by(&:year).map{ |ary| ary.group_by(&:month)}
```

Does anyone know a more beautiful (or at least working) way of doing this?

Comment: 1. This should be a question, not a question and an answer. You should remove the section "Solution". If you wish to say you are using a particular solution, do it as a comment on the applicable answer. If you wish to offer an answer yourself, do it as as an answer. 2. This question begs for an example. When you give an example show the expected or desired result and assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `arr =  [1,2,3]`) so readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments rather than defining them in their answer.

Comment: thanks @CarySwoveland , i improved my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How is this:

```
example_range.group_by {|date| [date.year, date.month] }.map {|_, month| month.first..month.last }
```

If you are using Active Support (Rails), this will also work:

```
example_range.group_by(&:beginning_of_month).map {|_, month| month.first..month.last }
```

Comment: I ended up doing this:

`example_range.group_by(&:beginning_of_month).each {|_, month| month.first..month.last }`

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I think is this:

```
example_range.group_by {|date| date.month.to_s + "-" + date.year.to_s}
```

You can adjust the way you need.